# Is it possible to delete a Photo from the iPhone without alert view?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, photosframework, phasset

I use this method :

```
PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChangesAndWait({
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(assets)
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

                })
```

The effect of this method is to put to trash the Photos which are contained in assets.
But every time I do that, An alert view which says "Allow "application" to delete x photos ?" appears

Is there a solution to disable this alert view ?
Or to replace this alert view by a personal alert view which appears at an other moment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually no because this is a default behavior from ios framework for security reason.
If you want you can navigate through framework and see that he call alert